# Error at createIndex elasticsearch using ElasticsearchOperations. Why is the "BytesReference class was expected" exception happening?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I used org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch version 6.8 and for connectivity I used TransportClient. I then decided to upgrade to version 7.6 and since TransportClient is Deprecated, I had to use the connection to elastic via the RestHighLevelClient. After this, the following error appeared after the start:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference, but class was expected
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.createEntity(RequestConverters.java:689)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.createEntity(RequestConverters.java:684)
at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesRequestConverters.createIndex(IndicesRequestConverters.java:128)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1760)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1734)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1696)
at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create(IndicesClient.java:191)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.createIndex(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:1248)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.createIndex(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:1256)
```

It appears on the index creation line:

```
elasticsearchOperations.deleteIndex(clazz);
elasticsearchOperations.createIndex(clazz, loadFromFileSetting(pathSetting, someParams));
```

I use the following config class for connection:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.project.elastic.repository")
public class ElasticConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.elastic.url}")
    private String url;

    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        return RestClients.create(ClientConfiguration.create(url)).rest();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share you `pom.xml`?

Comment: yes, only gradle, it is here: https://gist.github.com/poznavaka/538489685e6014b617f2784c90f2c2d9

Comment: can you check if by any chance you have 2 versions of RestHighLevelClient in your class path, also can you share entire code base with proper instruction so that we can try it

Comment: I added implementation org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client and the error ended, but I got  "type is missing;7942: type is missing;7943..." error when i saved my model to elasticsearch

Comment: types are deprecated in ES 7.X, you need to pass `_doc` as type name to make it work

Comment: were u able to resolve issue?

Comment: yes, thanks. I resolved those problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211014/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-anton-magov).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to supplement [Opster Elasticsearch Ninja`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61046893/9485331). The problem described here has been solved by implementation *"org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.6.2"* in your gradle.build. After that you should indicate the index type as *_doc* and make sure that your java client version matches your Elasticsearch version.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by using the `_doc` in the Elasticsearch API as `types` are deprecated in Elasticsearch 7.X version and only `_doc` type is allowed for backward compatibility purpose and will be totally removed in Elasticsearch 8.X.

More information on [removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html) Elasticsearch official documentation.